# Batch Photo processing with Subdirectory support

Tags: windows, photography

I have a directory of photos with many many subdirectories (daily site photos for a construction site) each photo (Jpg format) is taken at full resolution and is about 4mb

I'm trying to find a program where I can reduce the jpg quality and overwrite the jpg in place

All the programs I've tried so far (listed below) have either no support for subdirectories or will search sub directories but place the processed photos in a common folder all together

any ideas?

Comment: I believe Adobe Photoshop's batch processing does this well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## BIMP Lite

It's a tiny and straightforward image processor with the ability to preserve subdirectories.

> BIMP Lite is a small and simple batch processor for image files, that allows you to perform various functions on multiple images. It can be used to create thumbnail images from your pictures, add a prefix/postfix (with meta variables), rename using a sequential number, change the case of filenames, replace/remove spaces & underscores, flip or rotate images and also apply anti-aliasing, inverse, greyscale and bevel effects. The thumbnail resizing allows you to force a specified width or height and keep the proportions, or define fixed image dimensions. Images can have text overlayed on them at any corner or side, as well as the center of the image. This text can include meta variables such as image height, width, number of colours etc. In addition, the program can also convert the file format to GIF, JPG, PNG, BMP, MIFF, TIFF, PCX or TGA.

It's also free.

[Download Link](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/bimp_lite.html)

Comment: Program keeps crashing But i think this is what I need

Comment: known issue that this software does not work with 8.1

Answer (score 2):

BatchPhoto can scan a folder with subfolders, resize your images and overwrite them in place. You can also select a better compression for JPEG.

BatchPhoto is very easy to use but packs a lot of features, including scripts and a completely automated mode (hot folders).

It's a paid program but you can try a fully functional trial from here:

[www.batchphoto.com](http://www.batchphoto.com)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Mini-Compressor](http://saturdaymp.com/mini_comp) would meet your needs.  You can right click on a folder full of pictures and it will compress all the photos inside the folder and sub folder.

It won't overwrite the original photos but instead create a new folder with a "_mini" suffix with your compressed pictures in it.  Any sub folders and photos will also have the "_mini" suffix.  Once the compression is complete you can delete your originals.

If you need all your photos to keep their original name then Mini-Compressor is not for you.  If you can live with the renamed compressed photo names give it shot.

Disclaimer: I'm the creator of Mini-Compressor.